# Some troubles with using sed and awk

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk

Right now I have some troubles. I'm finding a way to solve one problem. I have some file in the tree whose names are stdout-captured, stderr-captured and status-capture and I have to rename these files to stdout-expected, stderr-expected and status-expected. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's wrong with `mv stdout-captured stdout-expected` etc.?

Comment: not clear. Plese explain better what do you need.

Comment: is it "status-capture" or "status-captured" (like the others)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what we can discern of this question, you're attempting to create a programmatic rule to rename files ending in extensions `stdout-captured`, `stderr-captured`, and `status-captured` (assuming one typo)  into files ending in extensions `stdout-expected`, `stderr-expected`, and `status-expected`, respectively.  Obviously, if each of these definitions is inclusive of exactly one file, a rote `mv` may be more appropriate.

To perform the translation you desire with `sed`, simply invoke the following in `/bin/bash` with the desired target as your current working directory:

```
EXTENSION=stdout-captured
REPLACEMENT=stdout-expected
for arg in $(ls *.$EXTENSION); \
  do mv $arg $(echo $arg | sed s/\\.$EXTENSION/.$REPLACEMENT/); \
  done
```

... where `$EXTENSION` and `$REPLACEMENT` are defined for each of the cases that you wish to detect and replace for. This assumes no files contain `.$EXTENSION` anywhere in the remainder of the filename. `awk` is unnecessary for this solution.

For invoking this recursively across multiple directories, consider replacing `ls` with `find` and updating the rule accordingly. Note that `find` [has its own facilities](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) to perform operations on found resources, as well.